# Attributes running together or a URL query string in an unquoted attribute value

Tags: php

When running validator I am receiving this error. Alos, Internet Explorer 8 fails to load my sidebar in position. What I made wrong here ? TNX

```
global $layout;
echo '<div id=\"main\" role=\"main\" class=\"layout_" . $layout . "\">';
echo '<section id="content" class="grid_8 background_1">';
echo '<a id="main_btn" href="#"></a>';
echo '<div class="clearfix">';
echo '</div></div></div></div>';
```

Comment: Which validator? If HTML, then why not show the output? The PHP is irrelevant.

Comment: The output:   http://corpuriluminat.ro/product/iluminat-exterior/proiector-esparta-55-9349-z5-m3/

Answer (score 0):

The OUTPUT of line 2 is:

`<div id=\"main\" role=\"main\" class=\"layout_" . $layout . "\">`

Somehow, I doubt that's what you actually want. Try this instead:

`echo "<div id=\"main\" role=\"main\" class=\"layout_" . $layout . "\">";`

Comment: Tnx David. Already moved to the right. Checking again the code. Only IE8 fails...  http://corpuriluminat.ro/product/iluminat-exterior/proiector-esparta-55-9349-z5-m3/